# Calculate scroll count on scroll and auto slide with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a fullwidth slider on top of my website which has 4 slides. I wanna auto slide the slider (I use bxsliser) on every user scroll and then when user scroll 5th time move user to the next section.

Any thoghts how i can calculate the scroll count with jquery?

I have the slider height like this

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
    var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height(); 
    jQuery('.aboutStorySection').height(windowHeight);  
});
```

And i have scroll with jquery

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would possible be easier for us to help you if you created a snippet with the relevant code.

Comment: See my updated question @CarstenLøvboAndersen